# How to remove sharp edges in text-stroke css?

Tags: css

I have this code

```
-webkit-text-stroke: 30px #67676726;
text-shadow: 0px 4px 20px #d5d5d5,
0px 3px 0px #777777, 
0px 5px 0px #777777, 
0px 5px 0px #777777, 
0px 0px 15px #777777, 
0px 0px 15px #777777, 
0px 6px 0px #777777, 
0px 7px 0px #777777, 
0px 8px 0px #777777, 
0px 5px 0px #777777, 
0px 5px 0px #777777;
```

this is like a glass effect at the back of text. what I need is I want to remove the **sharp edges**

it's when I increase the width of **text-stroke**

[image]

It is much appreciated for those who can help me.

**PURE CSS** only

Answer (score 0):

You could try to wrap your text inside a `div` tag, add width and height and set the `overflow` to `hidden` so your edges get cut off.

Here an example:

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.text {
    margin: 40px;
    width: 160px;
    height: 39px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;

}

h1 {
    z-index: 999;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 20px #0e000026;
    text-shadow: 0px 4px 20px #d5d5d5,
        0px 3px 0px #777777,
        0px 5px 0px #777777,
        0px 5px 0px #777777,
        0px 0px 15px #777777,
        0px 0px 15px #777777,
        0px 6px 0px #777777,
        0px 7px 0px #777777,
        0px 8px 0px #777777,
        0px 5px 0px #777777,
        0px 5px 0px #777777;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
   <h1>LetterNVZ</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: No sorry doesn't look good :( I actually wanted it to be like border radius for each letters. that looks in square. But thanks!

Comment: @MarkSalvania Have you figured it out?